# Doubt on using reducers with MODIS sinusoidal projection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis

I am trying to extract the MODIS NDVI value for the pixel closest to a given point using the Python implementation of Google Earth Engine. The point is defined from Google Earth Coordinates (so WGS84) as:

```
siteCoords_features = [ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(14.116411,40.946856))];
pt_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(siteCoords_features);
geometry = pt_collection.geometry();
```

I then define the MODIS list of images as:

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1").filterBounds(pt_collection.geometry()).filterDate('2010-01-01','2020-12-31').select('NDVI');
datalist=dataset.toList(dataset.size());
```

Then a function for extracting data from an image and use the projection to avoid scaling errors:

```
def extractData(image):
dct=image.projection().getInfo()
lst=dct["transform"]
stats = image.reduceRegion(
    reducer=ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry=geometry,
    crs=image.projection().crs(),
    crsTransform=lst
);
return ee.Feature(geometry,{
    'value':stats.get('NDVI'),
    'hourStart':image.get('system:time_start'),
    'hourEnd':image.get('system:time_end'),
    'date':image.get('system:index'),
    'lat':geometry.coordinates().get(0),
    'lon':geometry.coordinates().get(1),
});
```

My question is, MODIS image projection is a sinusoidal one, while geometry is given in WGS-84. Does Google Earth Engine handles this differences or there is a mistake?

As far as I can see in the Google Earth Engine visualization the point is in the correct position and the clipping happens in a good region.

Also, if I verify that point on "raw" (i.e.: not reprojected to WGS-84) MODIS image downloaded from the NASA repository, the values seem to match.